# Facing a MQ issue on MQ channel

Tags: tibco-ems

I am experiencing MQ issue that if i start 1 application on 1MQ queue,it shows 1 listener on same queue but more than 1 session on MQ channel.Why sessions are created more than expected?We are using MQ connection through bindings file.
Below is the error:
There was an error when attempting to receive a message.com.ibm.mq.jms.SessionClosedException: MQJMS1024: session closed at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.waitForStart(MQSession.java:2391) at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receiveInternalQ(MQMessageConsumer.java:2388) at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receiveQ(MQMessageConsumer.java:2235) at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:4244) at com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSReceiver$SessionController.run(JMSReceiver.java:735)

Comment: It feels like you are talking about two different things that may be unrelated to each other. Try to flesh out your problem instead with exactly what you're doing and what happens. Are you for example connecting with a Java client, BW, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what release of MQ you're using or the platform, which would be useful.
In general, for MQ V7+, the reason there is more than 1 session from the QCF is because WAS uses multiple sessions for management functions for the QCF itself. If you're using an XA resource, there are threads used for that also.